# Wordpress login only from external database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, authentication

I have a Android App with non-wordpress database and another website with wordpress database, i want a single login for both of them, also when a user do any manipulations in App like changing password, so wordpress should check authentication from external database only.

Comment: Use Wordpress [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)